# hike for the timber?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"I don't know, Aunt Ray," he said dubiously; "this is hardly a woman's
affair.  If there's a **scrap of any kind, you hike for the timber**."
Which was Halsey's solicitous care for me, **put into vernacular**.

I've never seen this kind of 'idiom' in my life, the above 'hike for the timber'.
It doesn't look like an idiom though, but what's this anyway?

The 'put into vernacular' means 'put into word'?

A part of 'Circular Staircase' by Mary Rinehart.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It will help us help you if you can identify what dictionaries or other references you have consulted, and what you learned. I also encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing this expression.  (I've lived in the US Midwest for most of my 65 years.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put in vernacular is to put in common speech. I presume "hike for the timber" is idiom, akin to "head for the hills"; i.e., beat it, scram, skedaddle, get lost, make yourself scarce, vamoose. The point being that if people are arguing, it's best to get out of there pronto.

Answer (score -1):

Hike for the timber - run for the woods ......

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Lauren. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).
Your post would be improved if it included a reference and an explanation of why it answers the question.